# How to add private key pair in a firebase authentication server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Am trying to make an authentication module in an Android application using firebase

I tried using this
doc link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth?authuser=0

Please look Under heading **(before you begin)** ->Step 4 -> c

The file had been downloaded but I find no authentication server (In android studio or in firebase).

**So where do I copy this (.json) file?**

Comment: Your question is so unclear really if you are talking about .json file, the step 4 doesn't talk about that, in any case, the .json files goes in the root of your android project and you gotta change the build action on that file to `googleservicesjson`

Comment: @DheekshithMahalingam did you find an answer??